# Modifying WebHook Message With Discord.Net c#?

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

```
 using (DiscordWebhookClient client = new DiscordWebhookClient(WEBHOOK_URL))
{
   ulong z = 42342340290226;

   client.ModifyMessageAsync(ulong messageId, Action<WebhookMessageProperties> func, RequestOptions options = null)
}
```

How do I fill in the second and third parameters. These make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

The `Action<WebhookMessageProperties> func` is an action that will be applied to the message to modify it. For example,

```cs
Action<WebhookMessageProperties> func = message => message.Content = "Hello World!";
```

This would change the content of the message to "Hello World!".

The options can be used to specify parameters to the modification request, eg. time out. This can be left as `RequestOptions.Default` if you don't want/need any custom options. This would give an example call as:

```cs
client.ModifyMessageAsync(messageId, x=>x.Content="Hello World!", RequestOptions.Default);
```

Comment: what if I want the content to be an embed, How would i do this?

Comment: I want to add an embed to the message proties.